# Remove Perticulur Appended data Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let Suppose I Have A query As Below

```js
$(".categoryCB").change(function(){

        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
          var currentVal = $(this).val();
          $("#SqlQuerySpan2").append(" AND Category = " + currentVal);
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false)
        {
          $("#SqlQuerySpan2").text("");
        }

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>Search By Top Category</b></p>
<input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Silk Sarees">Silk Sarees
<input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Cotton Sarees">Cotton Sarees
<input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Designer Sarees">Designer Sarees
<input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Printed Sarees">Printed Sarees
                          
<br><hr>

<h4 id="SqlQuery">SELECT * FROM table WHERE city_id = 2<span id="SqlQuerySpan"></span> <span id="SqlQuerySpan2"></span></h4>
```

Code Works Fine. But Problem is I am using **[jquery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** So it will append data as i checks the checkbox but when i uncheck checkbox i wants to remove only perticulur data that are belongs with.

So How Can I Solve it..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is by replacing the value like this

```js
$(".categoryCB").change(function(){

        if($(this).prop("checked")){
          var currentVal = $(this).val();
          $("#SqlQuerySpan2").append(" AND Category = " + currentVal);
        }
        else
        {
         var currentVal = $(this).val();
          var str = $("#SqlQuerySpan2").text();
          str = str.replace(" AND Category = " + currentVal,"");
          $("#SqlQuerySpan2").text(str);
        }

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><b>Search By Top Category</b></p>
                          <p><input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Silk Sarees">Silk Sarees</p>
                          <p><input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Cotton Sarees">Cotton Sarees</p>
                          <p><input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Designer Sarees">Designer Sarees</p>
                          <p><input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Printed Sarees">Printed Sarees</p>
                          
<br><hr>

<h4 id="SqlQuery">SELECT * FROM table WHERE city_id = 2<span id="SqlQuerySpan"></span> <span id="SqlQuerySpan2"></span></h4>
```

**P.S** `if($(this).prop("checked") == true)` can become `if($(this).prop("checked"))`. This will return true, you don't have to compare with `true` and `else if(...)` can become `else`

Answer (score 1):

**Simple and Easy** :- Just change the else condition. Replace the unselected checkbox's value with blank.

```js
$(".categoryCB").change(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked"))
    $("#SqlQuerySpan2").append(" AND Category = " + $(this).val());
  else
    $("#SqlQuerySpan2").text($("#SqlQuerySpan2").html().replace(" AND Category = " + $(this).val(), ""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>Search By Top Category</b></p>
<input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Silk Sarees">Silk Sarees
<input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Cotton Sarees">Cotton Sarees
<input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Designer Sarees">Designer Sarees
<input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Printed Sarees">Printed Sarees
<br><hr>
<h4 id="SqlQuery">SELECT * FROM table WHERE city_id = 2<span id="SqlQuerySpan"></span> <span id="SqlQuerySpan2"></span></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` method to create array from all input values and then `join` method to get string from that array.

```js
$(".categoryCB").change(function() {
  let text = $('.categoryCB')
    .map(function() {
      return $(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val()
    }).get().filter(e => e).join(" AND Category = ")
  
  text = text.length ? " AND Category = " + text : ''
  $('#SqlQuerySpan2').text(text)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><b>Search By Top Category</b></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Silk Sarees">Silk Sarees</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Cotton Sarees">Cotton Sarees</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Designer Sarees">Designer Sarees</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="categoryCB" value="Printed Sarees">Printed Sarees</p>

<br>
<hr>

<h4 id="SqlQuery">SELECT * FROM table WHERE city_id = 2<span id="SqlQuerySpan"></span> <span id="SqlQuerySpan2"></span></h4>
```